# Share JavaScript file resources with another Javascript without using HTML

Tags: javascript

I need to use the functions of a javaScript file in another javaScript file, but I do not have an HTML linking the 2, how to share it?

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver')
var chrome = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
login(chrome);
```

this is my code main and i need get this other method to other JavaScript File.

```
function login(chrome, user, senha){
chrome.get('https://testerbeta.crm2.dynamics.com/main.aspx');
}
```

now the code is small, but the software that I have to test is great and I need to separate the methods in different javascripts files

Comment: What's your JavaScript runtime?

Comment: global variable?

Comment: If it's node, look up how to use a basic `module.exports = ...` pattern. If it's client-side, then I don't even understand how you're using the javascript _without_ an HTML file linking the two.

Comment: @Timo I use Nodejs to execute JavaScript file

Comment: @MattFletcher I use the JavaScript File to SeleniumTest

Comment: @eramit2010 don't work with Global variable, i try it

Comment: @Lektransao Okay, well it seems it may be a selenium issue rather than just plain javascript. Could you please add a little more detail in your question, showing your selenium setup and the like? And also possibly add the selenium tag?

Comment: OK, one second @MattFletcher

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are `import` and `export`, added in ES6.

Basically, in the file you want to get your functions from, just add `export` keyword before function declarement, just like that:

```
export function foo() {
    return bar;
}
```

Then, in the file you want to inject your function in, you add this at the beginning of the file:

```
import { foo } from 'path/to/your/file_with_function_to_export.js'
```

More about that you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).